# Howto convert my angular app into Http Mode

Tags: angular

I have created an angular project Before It was working very well but I don't no the reason suddenly some Issues are coming for my application.

When I compress the code using

```
  ng build --prod
```

When I am trying to serve the application through Nginx it is not all loading the landing page, It is showing blank, when I have checked the console I am getting like this:

```
GET https://**-******-app.***india.cloudapp.azure.com/styles.a7a2574f943016f18461.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I don't no why it is running on "Https" Mode.

Another issue is :

When I am trying to access the APIs which are running on server, I am calling the APIs through Locally from Angular App Still I am not able to call the APIs.

My APIs and UI are running on HTTP Mode only but I don't no where It is converting into HTTPS.

I have used CURL Command to test the APIs. Using HTTP Mode I can call the API but not HTTPS.

Can anyone help me on this?

I don't no where the problem is, So I think the problem is from the angular side so I have kept tag as Angular, If am wrong please correct me.

Comment: Try making a request with curl or wget, does this work?

Comment: @Henry I don't have any SSL certification to run the APIs and UI on Https  Mode, I have some previous compressed block If I use that they are working fine, but I don't no this error is coming right now. Both APIs and UI are running Http Mode only